# How to Generate this HTML in Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

How can I generate this HTML using Jade

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" href="#websiteModal">
<i class=" icon-map-marker icon-white"></i>
Configure for Website</a>
```

I tried

```
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-large(data-toggle="modal",href="#websiteModal") Configure for Website
                i.icon-map-marker.icon-white
```

But it puts the `<i>` after "Configure for Website" text.

Comment: BTW, there is [html2jade](http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com/) available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do:

```
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-large(data-toggle="modal",href="#websiteModal")
  i.icon-map-marker.icon-white
  | Configure for Website
```

Or if you are feeling fancy:

```
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-large(data-toggle="modal",href="#websiteModal")='Configure for Website'
  i.icon-map-marker.icon-white
```